# executor.map and named parameter passing

Tags: python, concurrency, iterator, future, map-function

I have a case of a function which must be run with a large number of parameter types

```
# generic function with named parameters
def genericFn(X, y, a_fn ='t', o_fn ='a', l_fn='b', dim=2):
   ...
  return accuracy
```

I have a list of parameter types

```
a_fns = ['t', 's', 'r', 'l']
o_fns = ['s', 'a']
l_fns = ['m', 'h', 'l', 'b', 'k', 'p']
```

How can I pass every possible combination of the functions to the pool

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
  results_list = executor.map(genericFn, (combinations of named parameters))
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you need to adapt examples to your needs.
You could use something like this:

```
from functools import partial

class dict_to_kwargs:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, arg, **kwargs):
        return self.func(**kwargs, **arg)

class your_class:
    def your_method(self):
        result_executor = executor.map(
                    dict_to_kwargs(
                        partial(
                            method_name_to_map,
                            named_param_1=named_unvariable_param_1_value,
                            named_param_2=named_unvariable_param_2_value,
                            named_param_3=named_unvariable_param_3_value,
                            named_param_4=named_unvariable_param_4_value,
                            named_param_5=named_unvariable_param_5_value,
                        )
                    ),
                    [{"named_param_6": x} for x in named_variable_param_6_values],
                )
        return list(result_executor) # to return it like a list
```

- '**method_name_to_map**' is the method you want to send params to and iterate.
- '**named_unvariable_param**' is for values that should be the same on each iteration.
- '**named_variable_param**' if for you to pass params that are variable and should be iterated.
- '**dict_to_kwargs** class' is one of the tricks here. It is used to convert what you pass, as kwargs.
- '**partial** method' per documentation:

> "Return a new partial object which when called will behave like func
> called with the positional arguments args and keyword arguments
> keywords. If more arguments are supplied to the call, they are
> appended to args. If additional keyword arguments are supplied, they
> extend and override keywords."